# we need simply multiply with hh:mm * 1234 in crystal reports

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, formula

I have a field format that is hh:mm (8.30)and another field type is a Number like 60 and I want the result 510*60 = 30600.
please help me.

Answer (score 0):

To get the number of seconds from your 8.3 field (assuming it is called {HHMM_TimeAsNumber}) use this expression:

```
Floor({HHMM_TimeAsNumber}) * 60 + 100*Remainder({HHMM_TimeAsNumber},1);
```

If it is a text field, convert it to a number first.